# Como fazer com que a execução do sintetizador não seja interropida?

Tags: python-2.7

Estou tentando fazer um programa que, quando eu pressiono uma tecla, ele lê qual tecla foi pressionada.

Por exemplo:

pressiono a tecla "a" retorna: "Normal Key A" (em áudio)

pressiono a tecla "b" retorna: "Normal Key B" (em áudio)

pressiono a tecla "7" retorna: "Normal Key 7" (em áudio)

pressiono a tecla "!" retorna: "Ponctuation Key !" (em áudio)

pressiono a tecla "Shift" retorna: "Especial Key Shift" (em áudio)

Por um motivo que desconheço, ele só funciona normalmente quando a 1a teclada é pressionada,a partir da segunda o áudio é cortado.

Por favor, me ajudem!

```
import pyttsx
engine = pyttsx.init()

from Tkinter import *

def key(event):
    if event.char == event.keysym:
        msg = 'Normal Key %r' % event.char
    elif len(event.char) == 1:
        msg = 'Punctuation Key %r (%r)' % (event.keysym, event.char)
    else:
        msg = 'Special Key %r' % event.keysym
    label1.config(text=msg)

    engine.say(msg)
    engine.runAndWait()

root = Tk()
prompt = '      Press any key      '
label1 = Label(root, text=prompt, width=len(prompt), bg='yellow')
label1.pack()

root.bind_all('<Key>', key)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Isabela não compreendi muito bem o que vc quis dizer com: *ele só funciona normalmente quando a 1a teclada é pressionada* poderia ser um pouco mais clara por gentileza?

Comment: @gato quando eu pressiono a tecla A, por exemplo, ouço: "Normal Key A", quando pressiono a tecla A novamente, ouço: "Nor" (o áudio não é executado até o final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra resolver meu problema bastou criar a instância "engine" dentro da função "key" e não fora como eu estava fazendo.

```
import pyttsx

from Tkinter import *

def key(event):
    engine = pyttsx.init()                  # A MUDANÇA ESTÁ AQUI
    if event.char == event.keysym:
        msg = 'Normal Key %r' % event.char
    elif len(event.char) == 1:
        msg = 'Punctuation Key %r (%r)' % (event.keysym, event.char)
    else:
        msg = 'Special Key %r' % event.keysym
    label1.config(text=msg)

    engine.say(msg)
    engine.runAndWait()

root = Tk()
prompt = '      Press any key      '
label1 = Label(root, text=prompt, width=len(prompt), bg='yellow')
label1.pack()

root.bind_all('<Key>', key)

root.mainloop()
```